# How to attach an image icon to the `UIActivityViewController`?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

How to attach an image icon to the `UIActivityViewController`?

When I do

```
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
          activityItems: [ 
                           UIImage(named: "imageName")!,
                           urlName, 
                           urlProduct
                         ], 
         applicationActivities: nil)
```

it doesn't work

[image: the selected frame marked in red]

Comment: What does it depend on? It cannot be controlled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `LinkMetadata` using `activityViewControllerLinkMetadata` method:

```
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        // define your metadata here
        return metadata
    }
```

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityitemsource/3144571-activityviewcontrollerlinkmetada?language=swift

Comment: That is for links. This is a UIImage.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? I'm new in PLLinkMetadata :)

Comment: @MichelRivera added link to the docs, it contains an example of how to add the image.